# which phrase is right ,"perform type" or "perform analysis"?

Tags: meaning, of-phrases

When reading a book about Algorithms, I meet one sentence:

> We will demonstrate how to **perform this type of running-time analysis** to recursive algorithms.

Here is my question:

- **this type** should be the object of verb **perform** according to position relationship. But I think **perform analysis** is more reasonable according to the meaning. So which comprehension is right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in inferring that what is performed is an *analysis*, not a *type*.

But the construction is not misleading. A *type of X*, or a *kind, sort, variety, category of X* does not denote something different from *X*; it denotes a subset of the class *X*. That is, there are presumably many analyses which may be described as 'running-time analyses'; when the authors write that they will "demonstrate how to perform this type of running-time analysis" they are understood to mean that they will demonstrate how to perform the running-time analyses which belong to *this type*—the type which has previously been described.